# C++ std::map - thread safe if one thread writes and another reads with always different keys?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, stdmap

Thread A writes to the std::map with key C

Thread B reads from std::map with key D

If it is always guaranteed that the keys do not overlap, is this thread safe?

Since std::map uses a tree-structure inside, I could imagine that there could be problems to read from it while it is being mutated.

If std::map does not work, would std::unordered_map be better?

Comment: is the existance of the keys guaranteed?

Comment: **No**.  If you have a writer and a reader you need some sort of synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If by writing you mean changing the value of an **already existing
  entry** associated with key C, then the answer is (I believe) **YES**.
- If by writing you mean (potentially) inserting **new elements** (or removing them), then the answer is definitively **NO**.

Although not an authoritative source, [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/) usually has a section about potential data races for each function.

Comment: For the first part it depends what is in the map.  If the value is a pointer and `D` and `C` both have the same pointer then you could have a write while you are reading.

Comment: @NathanOliver strictly speaking, then you would be *reading* the map in both threads. Changing the value in a map of pointers would make the element point somewhere else.

Comment: @user2079303 I was talking about changing the value of what the pointer points to.  If the values are pointers and one thread changes the value of what the pointer points to and the other thread is reading it at the same time then you have a torn read and UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know what you're talking about and I don't disagree. My point is that it's not very relevant to the question or this answer.

Comment: @user2079303 Why. If the is what the OP has then he is going to think this is okay.  A blanket yes should not be the answer but a "it depends on the situation"

Comment: Well, thank you guys. This is enough reason for me not to do it.

Comment: @NathanOliver: How does writing to an object that is pointed to by a pointer in the map constitute as *"changing the value of an entry"*?